# Latex file and pdf viewer

Tags: pdf, compiling

When I apply the command (build and view), I get the beginning of the pdf file. How can I get immediately the change in the pdf file after I do (build and view) in the Latex file.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: latex itself does not have any build and view  command or pdf viewer so you are presumably asking about a menu option in some editor, but you have not said what editor you are using with your latex documents.